Gazebo Migration - Topic bridge
Thanks again to the Gazebo devs for the Gazebo Migration guide.
I see that in the guide Gazebo topics are bridged one-by-one to ros2. Is there any option to bridge all topics in both directions by default?
Thank you in advance to anyone that can clarify this.
